# Zend Framework 2 Sql\Select adding " quotation marks into query

Tags: zend-framework2

I've written out a very simple query in using ZF2's Sql Object...

```
$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
$select = $sql->select()
->from('school')
->where(array("id = ?" => $id));
```

echo $select->getSqlString();

However, the query this returns contains "quotation marks" around the table name...

```
SELECT "school".* FROM "school" WHERE id = '4'
```

This obviously renders the query incorrect. Does anyone know why it does this and how to stop it?

Comment: That's not an issue, the query should still execute fine. This is just the way it gets output from this method.
Try executing it and you will see :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I couldn't get it to execute without throwing up a sql query error. The only thing that I could see that looked incorrect was the quotation marks in the query output.

Comment: what was the error, was it definitely an SQL sytax error? that should work fine as it is

Comment: You can also get rid of the '?' this is fine:
->where(array("id" => $id));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the getSqlString method is nonsense. If you look inside it you can see that it doesn't pass the driver information into a function that render the SQL string. In result the renderer assume some default query template and simply quote the value instead of using Mysql template.

Try using this:

```
$select = $sql->select()
    ->from('school')
    ->where(array("id = ?" => $id));
$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
$selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
```

If found this after few hours of trying to render "limit" clause properly using only Zend\Db\Sql\Select object.